# Having issues with Cron jobs

Tags: php, email, cron

I've been having an issue with one of my cron jobs recently, and for the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out.

Every so often, I get an email regarding this error:

```
strpos(): Empty delimiter in
/home/.sites/28/site1/web/includes/localization.php on line 119
```

with the subject header of this:

```
Cron <vps> cd /home/.sites/28/site1/web/ && /home/php/bin/php -f dat/cron.php
```

Easy enough, I go and look at the line of code on line 119, which looks like this:

```
if (strpos($pageName, $webRoot) === 0).
```

Now, I'm assuming that above line of code is being called by the cron.php file. It's being called like this:

```
SendSMS(translate("cancel_sms", $request['languageID']), $request['phone']);
```

Am I correct in assuming that the issue lies with the part that says `$request['languageID']` ? Or am I missing the point entirely?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of errors occurs when `$webRoot` is empty. For example, if you set `$webRoot = ""` you could reproduce this error. You probably need to add some condition check in your logic to deal with the case when `$webRoot` is empty.